# Mixing bullet list and numbering - how to restart numbering after every bullet?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to create a multi level list, with bullet points and numbering. Everything is fine, all the levels are ok, however bullet points won't restart the numbering for me.
When I right click on the number and select *Restart* or *Set Numbering Value* the value will change and in an instant roll back to what it was before.

Of course, having multi level numbering list is fine, and they reset just ok, but I need to have a mix of bullet and numbering.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, are you right-clicking the number in the document and choosing from the context menu to restart/set numbering?

Comment: You shouldn't need to reset manually if you are using a multi-level list. You just have to set the list correctly. Can you do some screen shots of your list configuration then we should be able to sort it.

Answer (score 1):

[@j_foster](https://superuser.com/questions/930319/mixing-bullet-list-and-numbering-how-to-restart-numbering-after-every-bullet#comment1260788_930319) & [@Julian Knight](https://superuser.com/questions/930319/mixing-bullet-list-and-numbering-how-to-restart-numbering-after-every-bullet#comment1260836_930319)

You were right, I had a mistake in my multilevel definition.

When changing definitions in Word 2010, there's the **More** button in the bottom left. After tapping it, there's an option to define that numbering should restart after *Level 1*. It seems for numbered lists this is done automatically, but for bulleted lists, this has to be done manually.

[image: Ms Word 2010 - Defining multilevel list]